# Making php login session variables different

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables

So I recently started using http://www.php-login.net/.
I have used it in several projects now.
But the problem is they all use the same $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] variable.
So when I log into one app, I get logged into all of them.

How can I prevent this?

Cheers!

Comment: One presumes that the projects are all hosted within the same DNS domain? Else the browser's cookie security would not provide PHP's session cookies across projects. Depending on how your projects are isolated (e.g. by subdomain/webroot?), you may be able to achieve the same by explicitly setting the cookies' domain or path attributes using [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) or setting [`session.cookie_path` and `session.cookie_domain`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path).

Comment: Else you can give each project's sessions their own name with [`session_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php).